# "full-expression" versus "full expression"

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, full-expression

I was looking at [this post](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2885#issuecomment-493592305) in GitHub, but I couldn't understand what the OP meant by this:

`"full expression" suggest that it is a kind of expression, but sometimes it is not.`

My interpretation is that a "full-expression" (term used in the Standard) may not be an expression. [intro.execution]/5 gives the definition for full-expression, as follows:

> A *full-expression* is
>   (5.1) — an unevaluated operand (8.2),
>   (5.2)
>   — a constant-expression (8.6),
>   (5.3) — an init-declarator (Clause
>   11) or a mem-initializer (15.6.2), including the constituent
>   expressions of the initializer,
>   (5.4) — an invocation of a
>   destructor generated at the end of the lifetime of an object other
>   than a temporary object (15.2), or
>   (5.5) — an expression that is not
>   a subexpression of another expression and that is not otherwise part
>   of a full-expression.

If my interpretation is correct I would like to know which of the bullet points above yields a full-expression that is not an expression. Otherwise, i.e., if I'm wrong, what did the OP mean by his comment?

Comment: Since the thread was about whether or not to hyphenate "full-expression", OP could also have meant that removing the hyphen would make it more ambiguous to tell that it's actually an expression.

Comment: I think the discussion you refer to is just about distinguishing between "full expression" being not standard language while "full-expression" is

Comment: imho it would be better if you could rerphase the question to not refer to the posts on github. Only OP can know what they really meant with that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal list of expressions can be found in [[gram.expr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/gram.expr).  It is quite a bit of text so I am not going to include it here but using it we can see that an *init-declarator* and a *mem-initializer* are not expressions according to the grammar.  That means even though an *init-declarator* and a *mem-initializer* are considered  full expressions, grammatically they are not expressions.

Comment: Brilliant! But I'm still in doubt about the following: why did the spec have to include  a _declarator_ (used in the definition of a _init-declarator_) and a _mem-initializer-id_ (used in the definition of a _mem-initializer_), in the definition of a _full-expression_???

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Because they are full expressions.  That is why you can do things like `int i = 3, a = i++, b = i++;` or `foo(int i) : a(i++), b(i++) {}` and have defined behavior.  Each declarator is a full expression so there is no conflict for when `i++` is evaluated.  That same thing happens in member initializers.